# Are C++ expression value categories relevant outside of C++?

Tags: c++, expression, value-categories

I am learning about C++11 value categories for expressions. From my still superficial understanding, they were introduced as an additional type/category for expressions to disentangle compilation problems that could arise due to the possible presence of move semantics.

Also, if I understood well, value categories are not the same thing as the *type* of an expression, and there are 5 of them, and they have inheritance-like "is-a" relationships among them.

At a first glance, this all feels very peculiar and maybe a bit too complex.

I was wondering whether this complexity:

1. is fundamental and general (and therefore not avoidable) since it's coming from general theory around expressions, or
2. if it is just a C++'s quirk.

If it is the latter, is the reason behind this complex modeling due to C++'s historical accretion-style evolution, which constraints the design of the language to develop leaving every past design decision intact?

My interest in this question lies in the fact that: if we are under case 1), I will gain more motivation in getting acquainted with value categories intricacies, as I am interested in understanding programming languages in general at a fundamental level. In this case, could you give me a glimpse of how this theory is involved or used in the design of some other language?

If instead we are under case 2), it would still be very interesting to further study the topic and look for better, simpler, cleaner models for expressions and types/categories for them. Also in this case, any glimpse of how other languages handle those things?

Comment: It’s just a quirk.

Comment: It's not really that complicated once you've learnt it. There are only three distinct categories (lvalue, xvalue, prvalue), and the other two names are terms of convenience for grouping two categories together.

Comment: Maybe it would have been better if there were never the lvalue/rvalue distinction in the first place, and the language allowed you to write meaningless things like `3 = 5;`  (which would conceptually create a temporary of value 3, modify it, and destroy the temporary).  The horse has well and truly bolted on that one however

Comment: *"were introduced ... to disentangle compilation problems that could arise due to ... move semantics"* The categories existed even before move semantics.

Comment: It's a C++ quirk, and it is due to "accretion-style evolution" (which I'd call "valiant efforts to remain backwards compatible" for a language that has been wildly successful).  One of the big advantages that Haskell has had over C++ is its lack of success has enabled it to evolve more cleanly, since the crafters of Haskell are willing to break backwards compatibility (when there is good reason, not on a whim), and the small user community accepts that the language is evolving in that fashion.

Comment: I wrote a toy compiler for a language that used C++ value categories. This made it really easy to insert calls to copy/move constructors and destructors as well as allowing me to implement RVO and copy elision. I think it’s a great way of dealing with expressions and is not just a quirk of C++.

Comment: You need some kind of value category system or an extension to the type system to implement move semantics. It’s not a quirk, it’s the thing you need to do to get move semantics.

Comment: Just as note: C++17 completely revamped the way the specification works concerning value categories in an effort to simplify the whole thing (without changing the effective behavior). You might wanna have a look at that too.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Nice! Do you know where one could learn about those things? (For example, where to start from if I wanted to write a toy compiler supporting move semantics too)

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thank you I'll have a look!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not all of them were present before C++11, right?

Comment: @M.M I agree one could learn those and know them well. My question is if that is the "only and/or best way to go" or if there are out there better models, either already implemented in other languages or just living in the world of the "theoretically possible".

Comment: @MichelePiccolini Yup, in C++98 there were only lvalues and rvalues. In C++11 rvalues were separated into xvalues and prvalues.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'd categorise it as "In C++11 *the intersection* of lvalues and rvalues became xvalues, and the difference became lvalues and prvalues"

Comment: @MichelePiccolini Writing a toy compiler isn’t an easy thing to do. [My toy compiler](https://github.com/Kerndog73/STELA.git) ended up being about 20,000 lines of C++. To really understand value semantics in C++, you should read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category), [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization). Implementing this in a compiler will give you a better understanding but it’s not necessary if you just want to write good code.